# Retrieving elements based on object

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks a little like this:
slide      | title       | text
defautlt | No title | No text

With the top row being the header.
I then want to retrieve the title value with this code.

```
text = "default"
slideText[slideText$slide == text,]$title
```

This return
`character(0)`

But when I use
`slideText[slideText$slide == "default",]$title`

It return "No title" as intended.

Comment: `slideText` is the name of the df

Comment: You have value as "defautlt" in `slide` column. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
slideText[slideText$slide == text,'title']
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to work:
`slideText[slideText$slide == text,'title']`

Thanks to dvd280

Comment: you can mark the answer above correct if it solved your question :)